# Displaying images from mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning node.js at the moment and I am creating a little application where I can upload images and display them in a gallery.

Currently I have a form which uploads the image to the server via POST

```
extends ../layout
block content
.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3
  h1 control panel
    form(action="/upload", method="POST",
     enctype="multipart/form-     data")
      input(type="file", name='image')
      input(type="submit", value="Upload Image")
```

The file is then inserted to a mongodb using mongoose

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {  
fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {
    var imageName = req.files.image.name;
    if(!imageName){
        console.log("seems to be an
        error this file has not got a name");
        res.redirect("/");
        res.end();

    }else{
        var newimage = new Image();
        newimage.img.data = fs.readFileSync(req.files.image.path);
        newimage.img.name  = imageName;
        newimage.save(function (err, a) {
              if (err){
                  console.log("There was an error saving the image")
                  res.redirect("/");
                  res.end();
              }
        res.redirect("/gallery");
      });   
    }       
    });
    }
```

In my gallery controller I query the database for all the images and pass them to front-end.

```
exports.gallery = function (req, res) {
Image.find({}, function(err, image){
if (err)
  res.send(err);
else
    res.render("site/gallery", {images: image });
 });
}
```

And then in my gallery I try create a new image tag for each of the images

```
extends ../layout
block content
h1 Gallery
  each image in images
    img(src='#{image.img.data}')
```

My problem is that I keep getting a 404 error because the browser cannot find the image. 
But I have a feeling that I might be going about this the wrong way. I have seen GridFS but I feel that it is not suitable for this app as the amount of images in the gallery will be less than 20 max. Am I going about the right way to do this or should I be storing the images on the server and retrieving them that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would typically upload the images to your server's machine filesystem or to a static assets cloud hosting service like [AWS S3](http://aws.amazon.com/fr/s3/), and store only the *URL*s of the images in your database.

You could also use a solution like [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/).